# Request had "invalid authentication credentials". Expected OAuth 2 access token error in cloud speech api

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, console, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project**

giving this error , as i am not a cloud engineer... please explain the solutions bit

Comment: how do you query the speech api?